# Is each zero-dimensional cometrizable space zero-cometrizable?

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space $X$ is defined to be

$\bullet$ *cometrizable* if $X$ admits a weaker metrizable topology $\tau$ such that for every point $x\in X$ and a neighborhood $U_x\subseteq X$ of $x$ there exists a neighborhood $V_x\subseteq U_x$ of $x$ whose closure $\overline V_x^\tau$ in the metrizable topology is contained in $U_x$;

$\bullet$ *zero-cometrizable* if $X$ admits a weaker metrizable topology $\tau$ such that $X$ has a base of the topology consisting of open $\tau$-closed subsets in $X$.

> **Problem.** Is each zero-dimensional cometrizable space (with a countable network) zero-cometrizable?

Comment: Just so that I get this straight: the Sorgenfrey line is co-metrizable, with the normal metric topology as $\tau$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And it is zero-cometrizable by the second-countable topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by the subbase $\{(-\infty,a),[a,+\infty):a\in\mathbb Q\}$